# Azure Pipelines No certificate found with the supplied thumbprint

Tags: azure-devops

The issue is described [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/881015/no-certificate-found-with-the-supplied-thumbprint.html?childToView=1248035#).

TLDR;
I have a repository with .NET Solution Containing WPF application and WAP project. I created a pipeline to build the solution. The pipeline definition yaml file contains:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

When the pipeline runs in the build step I receive an error:

```
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(823,5): Error : No certificate found with the supplied thumbprint: 7FA3B996D434F774830FF22AE1A157751AFB419E
```

Comment: Do you have something similar `<PackageCertificateThumbprint>4594Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</PackageCertificateThumbprint>` in your csproj? If yes, try to create a new one to test. And how about the result if you build your solution in your local machine without Azure devops?

Comment: Hi, I have PackageCertificateThumbprint in my proj file. However it is not csproj but wapproj (Windows Application Packaging Project). I alredy tried to create a new one couple times.

There is something strange though Visual Studio shows warning:`The element 'PropertyGroup' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid child element 'PackageCertificateThumbprint'`

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know the specific cause of this problem, so please try the following:

1. As the error message says, the error is most likely due to your certificate. Try to generate a new certificate or cancel certificate validation.
2. Check your `.sln` file. If it has `PackageCertificateThumbprint` or `PackageCertificateKeyFile` parameter, check that it is configured correctly and that you have uploaded the correct certificate file to the appropriate path. Or try to delete the parameter and see if the problem is solved.
3. Make sure that the agent `windows-latest` has all the .NET SDK versions you need and all the software your project needs to reference. If not, use the task or command line to download them. Click [this link](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md) to view the software installed on the `windows-latest` agent.
4. Try to run the build project locally. If it is successful, try using the self-hosted Agent. Click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#download-and-configure-the-agent) for detailed steps.

Answer (score 0):

My Wpf app version is .net 5 and I had the same problem.I fixed it in this way in Azure Devops pipeline :
first I removed AppxPackageSigningEnabled and PackageCertificateThumbprint from wapproj file then I installed Code Signing task from azure devops marketplace and then add this task to my build pipeline after msbuild task. it signed my msix without problem.below picture is just a test and of course password should not be visible in not testing case.

[image]